# Remove whitespace from SVG

Tags: html, svg

I cannot find a way to alter the code below to remove the whitespace from a SVG image. What should I modify or remove to achieve this? I am editing the code using this website: https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor/

How the SVG image looks like with this code: See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8ad8.png).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="250.0px" height="100.0px" overflow="visible" viewBox="0.0 0.0 250.0 100.0" enable-background="new 0.0 0.0 250.0 100.0">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="Grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0021972656 0.0 0.0 0.0040893555 120.8 38.55)" r="819.2" cx="0" cy="0">

        </radialGradient>
        <linearGradient id="Grad2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0 0.001739502 -0.015563965 0.0 108.05 40.25)" x1="-819.2" y1="0" x2="819.2" y2="0">

        </linearGradient>
        <radialGradient id="Grad3" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.0021972656 0.0 0.0 0.0040893555 95.3 38.55)" r="819.2" cx="0" cy="0">

        </radialGradient>
        <linearGradient id="Grad4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0 -0.001953125 0.015563965 0.0 108.05 36.95)" x1="-819.2" y1="0" x2="819.2" y2="0">

        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g>
        <g transform="matrix(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0)">

            <path fill="#DC0100" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 232.05 57.75 L 230.45 60.6 L 221.85 68.25 L 221.5 67.9 C 221.2 67.6 220.84999 67.36666 220.45 67.2 L 221.9 61.85 L 223.5 62.4 L 226.05 57.25 L 227.2 57.85 L 229.95 55.95 L 232.05 57.75 Z M 227.85 82.2 L 226.65 83.0 L 226.65 86.35 L 224.2 87.15 L 222.5 84.45 L 219.6 84.75 L 219.0 84.7 L 219.25 80.35 L 219.35 80.35 C 221.61667 80.35 223.61667 79.75 225.35 78.55 L 227.85 82.2 Z M 212.3 82.8 C 211.23334 82.166664 210.25 81.416664 209.35 80.55 L 207.8 78.75 L 212.6 75.35 L 213.5 76.35 L 214.5 77.25 L 217.1 73.7 L 218.45 74.35 L 216.4 81.6 C 215.4 81.36667 214.46666 81.01667 213.6 80.55 L 212.3 82.8 Z M 205.15 70.3 L 201.75 68.9 L 202.25 65.6 L 205.85 65.6 C 206.45 63.8 207.4 62.15 208.7 60.65 L 207.25 58.15 L 209.1 56.2 L 211.7 58.1 L 213.75 61.2 C 213.11667 61.566666 212.53334 62.033333 212.0 62.6 C 210.43333 64.166664 209.45 65.96667 209.05 68.0 L 208.85 70.25 L 205.15 70.3 Z M 208.85 70.25 L 208.85 70.3 Z M 218.15 67.9 L 217.8 68.2 C 217.4 68.63333 217.18332 69.15 217.15 69.75 L 211.1 68.45 C 211.43333 66.816666 212.23334 65.36667 213.5 64.1 L 214.9 62.95 L 218.15 67.9 Z M 232.15 70.2 C 232.15 72.13333 231.76666 73.916664 231.0 75.55 L 223.55 72.0 C 223.78333 71.46667 223.9 70.88333 223.9 70.25 L 223.85 69.7 L 232.1 68.65 L 232.15 70.2 Z"/>
            <path fill="#6C0B0B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 226.05 57.25 L 223.5 62.4 L 221.9 61.85 L 220.45 67.2 C 220.85 67.36666 221.20001 67.6 221.5 67.9 L 221.85 68.25 L 230.45 60.6 C 231.85 62.166668 232.85 63.9 233.45 65.8 L 233.45 65.9 L 235.95 65.9 L 236.4 66.15 L 236.9 68.4 C 235.96666 68.86667 235.01666 69.35 234.05 69.85 L 234.05 69.95 L 234.05 70.3 C 234.05 72.23333 233.73334 74.01666 233.1 75.65 L 235.3 78.35 L 233.85 80.2 L 230.95 79.35 L 229.85 80.55 L 228.05 82.1 L 227.85 82.2 L 225.35 78.55 C 223.61667 79.75 221.61667 80.35 219.35 80.35 L 219.25 80.35 L 219.0 84.7 L 218.75 84.7 L 216.65 84.45 L 214.7 87.15 L 212.3 86.35 L 212.3 82.8 L 213.6 80.55 C 214.46666 81.01667 215.4 81.36667 216.4 81.6 L 218.45 74.35 L 217.1 73.7 L 214.5 77.25 L 213.5 76.35 L 212.6 75.35 L 207.8 78.75 L 205.55 80.35 L 203.85 78.2 L 206.05 75.5 C 205.45 73.9 205.15 72.16667 205.15 70.3 L 208.85 70.3 L 209.05 68.0 C 209.45 65.96667 210.43333 64.166664 212.0 62.6 C 212.53334 62.033333 213.11667 61.566666 213.75 61.2 L 211.7 58.1 C 213.43333 56.93333 215.35 56.216663 217.45 55.95 L 218.3 52.9 L 220.9 52.9 L 221.7 55.95 C 223.23334 56.11667 224.68333 56.550003 226.05 57.25 Z M 219.0 84.7 L 219.0 84.75 Z M 208.85 70.3 L 208.85 70.25 Z M 217.8 68.2 L 218.15 67.9 L 214.9 62.95 L 213.5 64.1 C 212.23334 65.36667 211.43333 66.816666 211.1 68.45 L 217.15 69.75 C 217.18333 69.15 217.40001 68.63333 217.8 68.2 Z M 231.0 75.55 C 231.76666 73.916664 232.15 72.13333 232.15 70.2 L 232.1 68.65 L 223.85 69.7 L 223.9 70.25 C 223.9 70.88333 223.78333 71.46667 223.55 72.0 L 231.0 75.55 Z"/>



        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adjust the viewBox so that it just covers the area you want. I've done most of it below, you could tighten if further if you need to.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="250.0px" height="100.0px" overflow="visible" viewBox="200.0 50.0 8.0 8.0" enable-background="new 0.0 0.0 250.0 100.0">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="Grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0021972656 0.0 0.0 0.0040893555 120.8 38.55)" r="819.2" cx="0" cy="0">

        </radialGradient>
        <linearGradient id="Grad2" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0 0.001739502 -0.015563965 0.0 108.05 40.25)" x1="-819.2" y1="0" x2="819.2" y2="0">

        </linearGradient>
        <radialGradient id="Grad3" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.0021972656 0.0 0.0 0.0040893555 95.3 38.55)" r="819.2" cx="0" cy="0">

        </radialGradient>
        <linearGradient id="Grad4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0 -0.001953125 0.015563965 0.0 108.05 36.95)" x1="-819.2" y1="0" x2="819.2" y2="0">

        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g>
        <g transform="matrix(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0)">

            <path fill="#DC0100" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 232.05 57.75 L 230.45 60.6 L 221.85 68.25 L 221.5 67.9 C 221.2 67.6 220.84999 67.36666 220.45 67.2 L 221.9 61.85 L 223.5 62.4 L 226.05 57.25 L 227.2 57.85 L 229.95 55.95 L 232.05 57.75 Z M 227.85 82.2 L 226.65 83.0 L 226.65 86.35 L 224.2 87.15 L 222.5 84.45 L 219.6 84.75 L 219.0 84.7 L 219.25 80.35 L 219.35 80.35 C 221.61667 80.35 223.61667 79.75 225.35 78.55 L 227.85 82.2 Z M 212.3 82.8 C 211.23334 82.166664 210.25 81.416664 209.35 80.55 L 207.8 78.75 L 212.6 75.35 L 213.5 76.35 L 214.5 77.25 L 217.1 73.7 L 218.45 74.35 L 216.4 81.6 C 215.4 81.36667 214.46666 81.01667 213.6 80.55 L 212.3 82.8 Z M 205.15 70.3 L 201.75 68.9 L 202.25 65.6 L 205.85 65.6 C 206.45 63.8 207.4 62.15 208.7 60.65 L 207.25 58.15 L 209.1 56.2 L 211.7 58.1 L 213.75 61.2 C 213.11667 61.566666 212.53334 62.033333 212.0 62.6 C 210.43333 64.166664 209.45 65.96667 209.05 68.0 L 208.85 70.25 L 205.15 70.3 Z M 208.85 70.25 L 208.85 70.3 Z M 218.15 67.9 L 217.8 68.2 C 217.4 68.63333 217.18332 69.15 217.15 69.75 L 211.1 68.45 C 211.43333 66.816666 212.23334 65.36667 213.5 64.1 L 214.9 62.95 L 218.15 67.9 Z M 232.15 70.2 C 232.15 72.13333 231.76666 73.916664 231.0 75.55 L 223.55 72.0 C 223.78333 71.46667 223.9 70.88333 223.9 70.25 L 223.85 69.7 L 232.1 68.65 L 232.15 70.2 Z"/>
            <path fill="#6C0B0B" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 226.05 57.25 L 223.5 62.4 L 221.9 61.85 L 220.45 67.2 C 220.85 67.36666 221.20001 67.6 221.5 67.9 L 221.85 68.25 L 230.45 60.6 C 231.85 62.166668 232.85 63.9 233.45 65.8 L 233.45 65.9 L 235.95 65.9 L 236.4 66.15 L 236.9 68.4 C 235.96666 68.86667 235.01666 69.35 234.05 69.85 L 234.05 69.95 L 234.05 70.3 C 234.05 72.23333 233.73334 74.01666 233.1 75.65 L 235.3 78.35 L 233.85 80.2 L 230.95 79.35 L 229.85 80.55 L 228.05 82.1 L 227.85 82.2 L 225.35 78.55 C 223.61667 79.75 221.61667 80.35 219.35 80.35 L 219.25 80.35 L 219.0 84.7 L 218.75 84.7 L 216.65 84.45 L 214.7 87.15 L 212.3 86.35 L 212.3 82.8 L 213.6 80.55 C 214.46666 81.01667 215.4 81.36667 216.4 81.6 L 218.45 74.35 L 217.1 73.7 L 214.5 77.25 L 213.5 76.35 L 212.6 75.35 L 207.8 78.75 L 205.55 80.35 L 203.85 78.2 L 206.05 75.5 C 205.45 73.9 205.15 72.16667 205.15 70.3 L 208.85 70.3 L 209.05 68.0 C 209.45 65.96667 210.43333 64.166664 212.0 62.6 C 212.53334 62.033333 213.11667 61.566666 213.75 61.2 L 211.7 58.1 C 213.43333 56.93333 215.35 56.216663 217.45 55.95 L 218.3 52.9 L 220.9 52.9 L 221.7 55.95 C 223.23334 56.11667 224.68333 56.550003 226.05 57.25 Z M 219.0 84.7 L 219.0 84.75 Z M 208.85 70.3 L 208.85 70.25 Z M 217.8 68.2 L 218.15 67.9 L 214.9 62.95 L 213.5 64.1 C 212.23334 65.36667 211.43333 66.816666 211.1 68.45 L 217.15 69.75 C 217.18333 69.15 217.40001 68.63333 217.8 68.2 Z M 231.0 75.55 C 231.76666 73.916664 232.15 72.13333 232.15 70.2 L 232.1 68.65 L 223.85 69.7 L 223.9 70.25 C 223.9 70.88333 223.78333 71.46667 223.55 72.0 L 231.0 75.55 Z"/>



        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: My question was how do we make it fit **just right**. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just carry on adjusting the viewBox till you think it does **fit just right**

Comment: I mean is there a way to make this happen easily and precisely with code? In a nonempirical fashion?

Comment: get the bounding box of the contents using getBBox and then set the viewBox accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a new programmer. That's why I asked the question here. Can you please do that in your answer? Thank you very much. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Found a web app which will remove the white space for you. Just copy/paste: https://svgcrop.com/

Answer (score 65):

Someone created a jsfiddle with a script that trims the svg for you which you can find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/knLbjc9a/4/).

Here's the script if you need to use it in your project:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", svg.outerHTML);
```

Additionally, @user2415116 linked another website that achieves similar results:
[svgcrop.com](https://svgcrop.com/)

Comment: In case anyone needs it, here is a modified version of the above which forces the SVG to be square https://jsfiddle.net/fr1ke0sm/1/, IE is adds padding to the shorter side

Comment: That js fiddle only trims X whitespaces, not Y whitespaces.

Comment: You just need this line ``var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ")``

Comment: Use https://svgcrop.com which is a bit more robust solution.

Comment: svgcrop.com achieved in 5 seconds what I'd been attempting for half an hour.

Answer (score 10):

Auto converter:
paste SVG in first textarea and get from second...

Note: *Run script in full page*

```js
      document.getElementById("p1").addEventListener('paste', function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          var x = document.createElement("div");
          x.innerHTML = that.value;
          document.body.appendChild(x);
          setTimeout(function() {
            var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
            var bbox = svg.getBBox();
            var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
            svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
            document.getElementById("p2").value = svg.outerHTML;
            svg.outerHTML = '';
          }, 1)
        }, 1);
      }, false);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea id="p1" style="width: 800px; height:400px;"></textarea>
    <hr>
    <textarea id="p2" style="width: 800px; height:400px;"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It gives me SVG with even more whitespace than before.

Comment: Yep, This may not always work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

You can copy your svg code into HTML input from [this website](https://codepen.io/mkmllr/pen/vpJmEK), then replace the `viewBox` in your svg code by the `viewBox` generated by the website, the whitespace in your svg image will be trimmed perfectly.

Comment: easiest and best solution imho!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Inkscape in command line interface mode (CLI). Below is the command...

```
inkscape --export-plain-svg --export-filename="your path to the edited svg" --export-area-drawing "path to the svg with whitspace"
```

Use this in conjunction with a shell script if you have many SVGs.

Comment: That was incredibly helpful. The problem with InkScape command line is that it has verbs and actions. Verbs can run only in gui mode. The obvious trimming verb is FitCanvasToSelection. Or so I thought. export-area-drawing is not obvious at all.