# white space around svg icon on web

Tags: html, css, svg

i use google material icon, and it has white space around it. When i apply sizing for the svg, it still keeps white space around it and the icon is tiny. 
  [image: tiny svg]
I add css to svg or a wrapper div it doesn't matter.

css

```
svg {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

html

```
<svg>
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/path.svg#ic_arrow_drop_down"></use>
</svg>
```

[image: arrow drop down]

the svg file contains

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none;">
... more symbols...
    <symbol id="ic_arrow_drop_down" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </symbol>
... more symbols...
</symbol>
```

Comment: I think we'll need to see the contents of the file path.svg in your assets folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove whitespace from SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683884/remove-whitespace-from-svg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the `viewBox` is the wrong size. Try `viewBox="7 10 10 10"`.

```css
svg {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="ic_arrow_drop_down" viewBox="7 10 10 10 ">
  <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z" />
</svg>
```

I think the second path is obsolete, I have removed it.

Comment: I'd honestly never even touched viewBox before :-) Thank you

Comment: A small explanation on why add 7 10 10 10 would've helped :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with this code, I could fix it

```
<svg class="icon icon-bookmark"><use xlink:href="#icon-bookmark"></use>
     <symbol id="icon-bookmark" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
          <path d="M6 0v32l10-10 10 10v-32z"></path>
     </symbol>
</svg>


.icon {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 8rem;
   height: 8rem;
   stroke-width: 0;
   stroke: currentColor;
   fill: currentColor;
```

}