# Trim SVG whitespace in .NET

Tags: .net, svg

I am trying to programmatically convert an SVG file into a PNG file. The SVG has some whitespace around the edges that I would like to get rid of. I want to trim the whitespace before converting to PNG, because the SVG size without whitespace will determine how large I need to scale the SVG.

---

Most of the help documents I've found are based around [HTML/JavaScript solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683884/remove-whitespace-from-svg), but I need to do this in .NET.

Here is the generally recommended approach I have seen on several sites, for HTML/JS:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", svg.outerHTML);
```

---

[SVG.NET](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG) seems to be the leading .NET SVG processing package, but the documentation is very sparse.

It looks like this library has API's to support the recommended JavaScript approach, but when I update the `ViewBox` and save, it looks just like the original image. Here is my F# attempt at this:

```
let svg = SvgDocument.Open("original.svg")
let bmp1 = svg.Draw()
bmp1.Save("original.png", ImageFormat.Png)

let bounds = svg.Bounds
svg.ViewBox <- SvgViewBox(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Width, bounds.Height)

let bmp2 = svg.Draw()
bmp2.Save("trimmed.png", ImageFormat.Png)
```

If I set a breakpoint and inspect the values of `Bounds`, it does seem to represent the content bounding box (excluding whitespace).

---

Another alternative I found was [GrapeCity.Documents.Imaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GrapeCity.Documents.Imaging/). This is less popular, but has much better documentation. However, it does not seem to expose any API for the SVG bounding box that I can find.

---

**How can I trim my SVG in .NET?**

Answer (score 0):

**Hacky brute-force workaround**

The general algorithm:

1. Render the SVG to BMP with no changes
2. Iterate the pixels of the BMP to find the bounding box
3. Determine the maximum scale that can be used to fit the bounding box in the container
4. Render the SVG to BMP again at the right scale
5. Scale the bounding box down
6. Crop the BMP to the scaled down bounding box

Here is a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesFaix/a549916806d9bed5cfcd50ee0c5ec0c4) with all the details.